# Table: sorting content with arrows

Tags: html, filter, html-table

I'm working on this website http://develop.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/table-test.html and as you can see there is a table of content with some "same columns": like **Zimmer: 4,5 - 3,5 - 2,5 etc**

My question is:

> is possible to filter the content with arrows? For example from 4,5 to 2,5?

Example:

[image: Table example]

Comment: How do you want to sort it? Through javascript? What kind of backend does your site use (if any)?

Comment: @Chris yeah with javascript could be great. I'm using Bootstrap to develop it

Comment: there are many answers on this already on this site. Here's one demo I found: http://jsfiddle.net/EQJqr/6/ from user @rab. Just add the arrows, but the sorting is there.

Comment: you can use datatable concept  as it is by default providing sorting content with arrow.